# Angular 4 : how to send id of a user in modals bootstrap

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal, angular5

I'm working with Angular 4 as front end and spring boot as back end , i wanted to use bootstrap modals to show the details of a user while i click on a button 'user details' .

this is clients.component.html

```
    <!--/.col-->
<div class="col-lg-12">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      <i class="fa fa-align-justify"></i> Information des clients
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Numéro</th>
          <th>prenom</th>
          <th>nom</th>
          <th>Telephone</th>
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        <tr *ngFor="let c of pageClients?.content">
          <td>{{c.id}}</td>
          <td>{{c.prenom}}</td>
          <td>{{c.nom}}</td>
          <td>{{c.tel}}</td>
          <td><a (click)="delete(c)">delete</a> <a (click)="Edit(c.id)">Edit</a></td>
          <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary relative waves-light" data-toggle="modal"  (click)="largeModal.show()">
           user details
          </button>
          </td>
        </tr>

        </tbody>
      </table>

      <ul class="pagination">
        <li class="page-item" [ngClass]="{'active':i==currentPage}" *ngFor="let p of pages ; let i=index">
          <a class="page-link" (click)="gotoPage(i)">{{i}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div bsModal #largeModal="bs-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" (click)="largeModal.hide()" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="largeModal.hide()">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

when i click on details of client i get a large modal , i want to send id to this modal so i can include in it all a specific user's details ..

In client.component.ts :

```
import { Component, OnInit , ViewChild  } from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRoute, Router} from '@angular/router';
import {ClientService} from '../../../../../service/client.service';
import {Clients} from '../../Models/Clients';
import { ModalDirective } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-clients',
  templateUrl: './clients.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./clients.component.scss']
})
export class ClientsComponent implements OnInit {

  pageClients:any;
  pages:Array<number>;
  currentPage:number=0;
  page:number=0;
  size:number=5;
  public largeModal;

  constructor(private router:Router,
              private clientService:ClientService,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.doSearch();
  }

  doSearch(){
    this.clientService.getClients(this.currentPage,this.size)
      .subscribe((data:any)=>{
        this.pageClients=data;
        this.pages=new Array(data.totalPages);
        console.log(this.pageClients);
      },err=>{
        console.log('this is error');
      })
  }

  gotoPage(i:number){
    this.currentPage = i;
    this.doSearch();
  }

  Edit(id:number){
    this.router.navigate(['edit',id], { relativeTo: this.route });
  }

  delete(p:Clients){
    let confirm = window.confirm('are you sur');
    if(confirm==true){
      this.clientService.deleteClient(p.id)
        .subscribe(data=>{
          this.pageClients.content.splice(
            this.pageClients.content.indexOf(p),1
          );
        },err=>{
          console.log(err);
        })
    }
  }


}
```

any idea ?

Comment: Which and what id do you want send, where will it be coming from? Is it a property of pageClients?

Comment: yes the id which is a property of pageClients : <td>{{c.id}}</td> this id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your modal is in the same component as the button to open it so you can pass your data in the component self.

Change your (click) handler to pass the id to a variable that you would reference in the modal.

Instead of `(click)="largeModal.show()"`, do something like `(click)="showModal(c.id)"`, then in your component:

```
showModal(id: number) {
    this.userId = id;
    this.largeModal.show();
}
```

Comment: Hi friend , i can get this id but the modal doesn't appear anymore , i get an error : ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'show' of undefined
    clientComponent.html:27 at ClientsComponent.showModal (clients.component.ts:69)

Comment: Are you using BsModalComponent library? If so, change your largeModal variable in your component to:
`@ViewChild('largeModal')
largeModal: BsModalComponent;`

Comment: I have imported the library ModalDirective from ngx-bootstrap/modal  , is it the same ? And in client.component.html i used bsModal #largeModal='bs-modal'

Comment: Alright there are multiple problems here but first off, try adding `@ViewChild('largeModal') largeModal;` and see if you can do this.largeModal.show() again. If not, follow the [docs](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#service-template) for your library to access the modalRef.

Comment: this worked as expected , thank you so much for help @ViewChild('largeModal') largeModal; was helpful

Comment: In fact i forgot about an important thing , i want next to pass the id to the model so it can show  the specific client's details .. how can i do that ? any idea ?